# Which is the fastet and the most efficient implementation in java for updating object in a list if present, else add it

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency, code-complexity

I have a problem statement which is working but still i would like to know more efficient, faster and more importantly correctly designed to handle the below mentioned scenario.

I have a POJO class

```
class A {
  String s;
  Double d;
}
```

I am trying to populate a List, basically a List of Object A into the list. Now the implementation in question. While adding the Object A into the list i need to check if an Object with String s already exists. If yes i want to update the older Object with old d1 + new d1 and do not add the new Object to the list, If no add the new Object to the list. My present implementation is something like below.

```
double dd = 0.0;
    List<A> aList = new List<A>();
    List<A> aListToRemove = new List<A>();
    A newA = null;
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++ ){
        newA = method call which returns newA;
        for(A oldA: aList ){
            if(oldA.getS().equals(newA.getS())){
                dd = oldA.getD() + newA.getD();
                newA.setD(dd);
                aListToRemove.add(oldA);
            }
            aList.add(newA);
            aList.removeAll(aListToRemove);
        }
    }

//at the end, i would like to see aList with no duplicates, but with updated d value.
```

Is there a more efficient way to do the processing within the second for loop?

Comment: Can i implement a comparator and somehow update the list when i call the List.add() method. This way the update and adding to the list and removing the older element will happen just on the call of add or compare method. Please educate me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you could use a map for your use case:

```
Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<> ();
```

and put items in the map like this:

```
map.put(someA.s, someA);
```

That should turn your O(n^2) algoritm into an O(n) algorithm.

When you receive a `newA`, you can use the following:

```
A a = map.get(newA.getS());
if (a == null) {
    map.put(newA.getS(), newA); //new string => new item in the map
} else {
    a.setD(a.getD() + newA.getD()); //found string => updating the existing item
}
```

Comment: In this approach will the value for d get updated. That should be an additional step before i put into the Map right. I had mentioned i need value of d to be added.

Comment: Thanks, but i have a question. This implementation removes out additional Collection elements, but is it efficient enough in terms of performance, memory management etc..

Comment: @sandy it will certainly perform better than your example with 2 nested loops. Memory wise it will take a bit more space, but unless you work in a memory-constrained environment it should not be an issue (probably a few bytes per object, which unless you have billions of them should be ok).

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a `List`? It sounds like a `Map` could do the job for you. Specifically, the [`put()` operation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) adds or replaces a key-value pair, which fits your semantics perfectly.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

If you want efficiency, I would use a [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) or `Map<String, List<String>>` This will mroe more efficient to not only perform the lookup but the accumulation of data. If you need to append the String together, the best option could be to use a `Map<String, double[]>`

```
class A {
  String s;
  double d; // don't use Double unless you need null values.
}

Map<String, double[]> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

for(A newA: getAs()) {
    double[] total = map.get(newA.getS());
    if (total== null)
        map.put(newA.getS(), total = new double[0]);
    total[0] += newA.getD();
}
```

This will give you O(1) lookup and accumulate the values with a minimum of object creation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You can check if an item is in the map with the get method (it seems s would be the key):

```
A a = myMap.get(newA.getS());
if (a != null){
 a.setD(a.getD() + newA.getD());
} else {
 myMap.put(newA);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `java.util.Set` for your operations.

You can check the existence of your object in O(1) time and perform your operation accordingly.

It will also take care of removing the duplicates.

```
   double dd = 0.0;
    Set<A> aList = new HashSet<A>();
    A newA = null;
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++ ){
        newA = //method call which returns newA;
        A oldA = aList.get(newA);
        if(oldA != null){
           aList.remove(oldA);
        }
        dd = oldA.getD() + newA.getD();
        newA.setD(dd);
        aList.add(newA);
    }
```

Please make sure you override your `equals` and `hashcode()` methods in class A which will be used by `Set` else the default implementation will be used

Comment: you can always remove the old entry and insert a new entry in the set. it is also an O(1) operation

Comment: True, but it adds complexity and a `Map` is really a better choice.

Comment: Yep, one extra removal operation is required in case of Set. but if you add more fields in this object and the equality of the object depends on more fields than just S in current case, then Set will not require any changes in implementation whereas the Map implementation needs to change completely

Comment: That would anyway be required in Map implementation as well.

Comment: Actually not, read the last paragraph in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: The problem is too many collection elements. Also when i deal with like 50K records, there is likelihood of Java Heap Space problem. Am looking for a simpler and effective approach .

Comment: 50k elements will hardly take 1 MB in memory assuming each entry to take approx 20 byes.